# Auto login security with PHP, how and why

Tags: php, security

I know this question has been asked many times, but I have a little different spin to it. It's a two part question.

First, I am implementing an auto login and I'd like to know where any holes are in my workflow.

Second, I'm unclear as to how a hacker would use the information they stole to compromise a system.

---

The first part, here is my workflow, what parts are vulnerable. Here are a few things that may, or may not, be helpful to know, I'm using PHP 5.6.21. I will be using their new hash API that uses the latest hashing technology and automatically salts it. I'm using the MVC architecture, so pretty much everything, other than my front controller and personal assets, are outside the root of the web server.

1. A member logs in and selects the auto login checkbox
2. A cookie with a hash value, that matches a hash value in the members table, is written to their browser. The cookie is only accessible from the members directory on the server, which is outside the root directory. Also, the httpOnly attribute is set.
3. The next time the member logs in, there is a check to see if that cookie exists, if so use the hash value as a key to lookup the member in the member table.
4. If they are found, log them in. If the cookie was set, but no matching record was found, then it's possible the cookie was tampered with. In that case, create a new auto login hash in the database and delete the cookie in the members browser. Then, force them to log in manually. If they choose auto login again, it goes back to step 1, this time using the new hash.

So, its pretty straight forward and no user data is stored in the cookie, just a meaningless hash.

---

The second part of my question is more general. Let's say a hacker somehow compromises the auto login cookie and gets the has code. What can they do with it? How can they use that to compromise my system?

In the case of SQL Injection, I understand that a data dump may be possible and a hacker could get a read only view of your database. In which case having hashed and salted passwords is a must! They can run those hashes through their evil machines and possible get your login credentials.

I was reading some security paper on why it is important to take all these measures. It kept saying that if a hacker get access to your database... But, if a hacker gets access to your database (with write privileges), none of this matters because you're screwed no matter how strong your hashes are.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I'm assuming all communication in part 1 is via HTTPS?

Comment: I assume your login is completely under a secure shell and that the cookie itself is only available over HTTPS - otherwise transfer of the cookie data is unencrypted between the client and server and the cookie can be intercepted (e.g. if used in a public wifi hotspot).

Comment: I don't think this question is off-topic, *but* you might get better answers at http://security.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Oops I messed up step 4 in my workflow. If the cookie is set, but no record is found, I can't create a new hash in the database because I don't know who's hash to recreate. So, after the member successfully logged in again manually, then a new hash would be created in the database and that new hash would be written in a new cookie.

Comment: Yes Ray, it's not at the moment because I'm developing locally, but by the time it's in production that will all be encrypted by SSL and I will also add the security attribute to the cookie so that it can only be transmitted over SSL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two parts to this:

1. Making sure your sessions are secure. [Read this](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/fast-track-safe-and-secure-php-sessions) for a primer on session security, with configuration examples. Spoiler: HTTPS is mandatory, make sure you're using a CSPRNG for session identifiers, and you're regenerating session IDs during privilege escalation (and/or regularly).
2. Safely implementing a cookie-based authentication token that will transparently re-authenticate the user when they access your website with a valid cookie but without an active session. I've previously written extensively abut [side-channel-resistant persistent user authentication](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence#title.2.1).

The second part is more interesting, because many people stop at the "generate a random token, store in a cookie, and then look it up in the database" step.

You're safe to assume that your heavily-optimized database query isn't comparing strings in constant-time, like you need to be in order to prevent timing attacks.

The solution is to break your token into two pieces: One for the database lookup (timing-leaky), and the other for comparing in constant-time.

- The first piece (called the selector) is stored/indexed in your database table.
- The second (called the verifier) piece is stored in plaintext in your user's cookie, but is hashed (e.g. SHA256) in the database.

After retrieving the token based on the selector, you compare the hash of the verifier provided by the user with the stored hash, using [hash_equals()](https://secure.php.net/hash_equals).

Each long-term authentication token should only be used once. Afterwards, a replacement should be issued to the end user. Logging out should clear the cookie, while the session should expire when the browser is closed.

**This is only secure if you're using HTTPS with HSTS, and your cookies are set to HTTPS-only!** (This means `secure` and `httpOnly` are both set to `true`.)

You can see an example of this system in action [here](https://github.com/paragonie/airship/blob/5cfebe3ba091c17d39d424a5eb731739d6b3cf99/src/Engine/Security/Authentication.php#L94-L118) and [here](https://github.com/paragonie/airship/blob/5cfebe3ba091c17d39d424a5eb731739d6b3cf99/src/Engine/Security/Authentication.php#L167-L219).

Comment: This is great! Not just how to implement the security, but why I'm doing it. I'm going to implement these measures in my system now that I understand why I should.

Comment: I really like the "selector:verifier" approach to protect against a leaked database. Very cool.  However, as Adam states below, some extra piece of information, like IP or user agent, encoded in the cookie would help even if someone stole the cookie from a client, though not perfect.

Comment: That's not your concern as a web developer. Don't use IP addresses or user agents as an identifier. What happens if they're on a mobile device and roaming, or their browser updates and changes the UA version? Or if they're a Tor user? It's fragile. Better to make client-side security the client's problem.

Comment: imo, Really good explanation of how to use 'user login' and 'autologin cookies properly'.  Mind if I reference this in my profile and comments about user login? It is good.

Comment: Yep that was some good stuff, all of it, not just the part about auto login. I'm implementing these techniques now! I'm with @Scott on the IP address and user agent. With PC's, laptops, tablets, cell phones, dynamic IP addresses, access from various hot spots, etc. There is way too many variations of user clients and IP addresses you will be accessing from. That is too limiting in my view. I really like the selector:view idea, making sure you use an encrypted connection (HTTPS) and locking down your cookies with httponly and security attributes.

Comment: I disagree @Scott Arciszewski : this is an autologin feature not a session feature. Maybe it doesn't work from a few weird cases, but for most people it is an extra layer of protection.

Comment: It's not a necessary one. The only way their cookie is going to get stolen is malware. Or, you failed to implement the parts that *are* your responsibility correctly. Many speed-bumps doesn't make a wall. And this *will* degrade usability significantly and create false positives if you log these IP/UA mismatches, too. The "protection" you imagine isn't a worthwhile trade-off. And obviously, if the client gets pwned, you can't save the client from the server's position.

Comment: IP is definitely a no-no, I agree. And, thinking about it, I suppose UA is easily faked if required, so I think I will change my position and agree with you! What can we lowly web developers do if our clients are infected? Not much - unless we go for MFA or similar.

Comment: MFA is a reasonable choice, but be careful not to take too much responsibility on yourself. If the client's machine is pwned, then you can't save them. If you detect anomalous behavior that indicates a hacked account trying to cause financial loss or reputation damage, by all means shut the account down to quarantine the affected user. But beyond that, it's totally out of your hands.

Answer (score 3):

When a user is required to enter a username and password every time he wishes to login, the only information stored client side is a cookie containing the `session id`. Now this is prone to `session hijacking`, which works on the principle that being client side, a user has full control of the session id sent to the server and in a non-secure environment, this is transmitted via HTTP (w/o any encryption). If a malicious user managed to get a hold of another user's session id, he could "hijack" that user's session.

There are ways to prevent or discourage session hijacking. One method is to whitelist the IP Address and/or browser information in the session. If the session conflicts with the "whitelisted" information, the session has been compromised.

Using your "auto-login" logic, your server only requires a *single* hashed string to gain access to a user's account. Since this hash is stored client-side, a user can "submit" any string they want in place of the hash. If the connection is not secured (HTTPS), and the network the user on is not necessarily trusted, a malicious user can [intercept](https://capec.mitre.org/data/definitions/31.html) the hash string. They could theoretically use that single hash string to login as the user.

At this point, your hash string, no matter how strong the algorithm was to generate it, is simply the new "username/password".

Most of the holes in the security depend on an insecure connection. If the connection is well-secured with a modern cypher-suite, I don't believe you'd be prone to the same issues.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand this part, " Since this hash is stored client-side, a user can "submit" any string they want in place of the hash. If the connection is not secured (HTTPS), and the network the user on is not necessarily trusted, a malicious user can intercept the hash string. They could theoretically use that single hash string to login as the user."

Comment: @keithmj cookies are stored on the user's computer. If you have Google Chrome, open dev tools, go to Resources -> Cookies. It is up to the browser to send the cookie back to the server. I.e. the user can hijack a someone else's cookie (through other means) and send that cookie instead of the cookie they should be sending.

Comment: How could any string be submitted and accepted if the string must match what's in the database? Also, by "submit" I'm assuming you mean submitting a form? If that's the case, when using the auto login, there is no form submission. It checks for the cookie and uses its value without any interaction by the user. Same with if a hacker steals the cookie value. They can't send that value to the server to get access. However, if they did steal it, they could create a cookie with that value on their client and then go to the login page and they would be auto-logged in. That would be bad!

Comment: Ok I get it, so I really need some sort of second check that goes along with the hash rather than just the hash by itself.

Comment: Not any string: an intercepted string (e.g. from public wifi). You don't need a form submission or user interaction. As long as the cookie gets from client to server, it is being communicated (generally in the initial HTTP request for the page). Any user can send their own 'custom' HTTP request. The problem is mitigated with HTTPS.

Comment: @keithmj The second check can be a simple comparison of info during the hash database lookup. Similar to what I mention regarding session hijacking.

Comment: Wow, this is super helpful! So as long as I'm using SSL in that transfer, my workflow should be pretty secure as is? However, it seems it would still be a good idea to come up with another authentication credential other than just the one hash.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all transport is secure (via HTTPS), the only reliable vector for an attacker would be stealing the cookie from a user's browser either physically or through some kind of browser exploit.

Some extra steps in regards to the auto login cookie could be taken such as:

- Storing an IP and locking that auto login token to a particular IP or a range around that IP, anything else could be deemed as suspicious activity and you could terminate the auto login key
- Storing the user agent and again, if it differs significantly (such as different browser) then it also could be unauthorised access and the auto login token should be revoked

In those cases it would be a good idea to notify the user that this has happened via email or another reliable option you have at your disposal.

Comment: Ok, I see I need something other than just the hash. As you suggested, an IP address would work well since it is unique. However, if the member logs in from more than one different device, say their computer and their phone. Then the auto login will only work for one of them?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a idea to protect against the situation in the second question: store the hash in a location other than the database. We have an app that stores authentication tokens in Memcached - a server-side key-value store in RAM. 
https://memcached.org/

We use a similar algorithm that you use here, except that we do a Memcached lookup instead of a database lookup.

Memcached has the additional advantage that you can set a timeout on how long a token is valid - allowing you to easily implement something where you log off after 30 minutes.